# jQuery conditionals with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON data where there is a field like such:

`"first_date": "2015-06-02"`

In jQuery, I'm wanting to basically say something like this:

```
if( valueOfFirstDate.substring(5, 6) == "06" ){
    //change 06 to "June"
}
```

How would I go about grabbing the value of that `first_date` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) to convert your string to an object

```
var json = '{"first_date": "2015-06-02"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
if(obj.first_date.substring(5, 6) == "06" ){
...
}
```

Comment: What if the value of the `first_date` field will no always be "2015-06-02"? Is there some kind of wild card I could use for the `var jsonString`?

Comment: That's just an example. You are getting the JSON data from somewhere, right? Just use the data you receive. For example if you're using `$.getJSON()` to fetch the data, the resulting object is passed into the success callback. You won't need the `JSON.parse()` either because jQuery does that for you.

Comment: @Jaken Herman: as long as `first_date` has always same format my code would work with any value.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I mean could I do something like `var jsonString = '{first_date : *}';`?

Comment: @Jaken Herman: well, obviously this code wouldn't work. You need to define all use case and paste that info on the question

Answer (score 1):

Just write something like that:

```
JsonObject.first_date
```

That's it. here your JsonObject is just any object of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could generalize this for all months:

```js
var obj    = { "first_date": "2015-06-02" },
    d      = obj['first_date'].split('-'),
    months = ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

obj['first_date'] = d[0] + '-' + months[ +d[1] ] + '-' + d[2];

alert( JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. Plain old javascript will work.

If you're given a json object then you can access the value with the key.

```
var obj = {
  "first_date" : "2015-06-02"
}

if (obj["first_date"].substring(5, 6) == "06") {
  //your code here
}
```

I would recommend that if you want to work with dates to use objects instead. It's always better to work with objects rather than strings. You can form a javascript object from a date string as well. Check out Mozilla Dev Documentation [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)